# Autosys - Is it possible to add timestamp to job error log?

Tags: autosys

Is there a way of time stamping Autosys job error file, if it is just STDERR redirection?

```
std_err_file: >>JOB_NAME.ERR
```

Comment: [Be wary of name collisions due to concurrency though.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/61685/201537)

Answer (score 1):

try using the date command.

```
bash-3.2$ date +%d-%m-%y.%H:%M
```

> 13-11-19.19:24

so using the above under ``

Add below attribute to your Job definition/ JIL

```
std_err_file: /dir_path/$AUTO_JOB_NAME-`date +%d-%m-%y.%H:%M`.ERR
```

The file directed would be

> /dir_path/AUTOSYS_JOB_A-13-11-19.19:24.ERR

Good Luck!!

Comment: Have adapted this to Windows: 
std_err_file: ">>JOB_NAME_%date:/=%.ERR"
It does not work this way unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can kindly try the below options. These work in command prompt of windows should work in autosys too.

Option1: Adding the date variables year month day in the file name while creating jill.

```
echo "Std out!" >> output_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log
echo "Std err!" >> error_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log
```

Option2: Adding a variable date_var in the autosys profile.

```
set date_var=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%

echo "Std out!" >> output_%date_var%.log
echo "Std err!" >> error_%date_var%.log
```

Option3: Similar to option2 but declaring the complete log names in profile itself.

```
set date_var=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set std_out=output_%date_var%.log
set std_err=error_%date_var%.log

echo "Std out!" >> %std_out%
echo "Std err!" >> %std_err%
```